# How to modify this navbar to hide on scroll down only after 100px?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navbar, offset

I currently have a navbar that on scroll down disappears and on scroll up reappears again (and is always visible when at the top of the page).

This works fine on desktop - the nav always shows when the page is at the top, but on mobile devices glitches and disappears completely when at the top of the page.

How would I amend this to be visible on scroll down for the first 100px, then disappear until user scrolls up?

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById('mainNav').style.top = '0';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mainNav').style.top = '-100px';
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos || currentScrollPos <= 100) {
     document.getElementById('mainNav').style.top = '0';
  } else {
     document.getElementById('mainNav').style.top = '-100px';
   }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can style element for scrolled and non-scrolled page. See the simple solution below:

```js
function update() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    window.document.body.classList.toggle('scrolled', window.pageYOffset > 100);
  });
}

window.onscroll = update;
window.onresize = update;
update();
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
}

#test { 
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body.scrolled #test { 
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Please scroll the page</div>
```